# Symfony2 exceptions at user authentication process

Tags: php, symfony

I think that Symfony2 catches and ignores every exception thrown at user authentication process. Is there any way to change this behaviour?

Comment: It doesn't ignore it, simply catches it. You could implement exception handler to handle the situation. Why would you need to change this behaviour?

Comment: I want exception to break everything possible when debugging my application.